# array gives unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,6];
let arr2 = arr
arr = []
console.log(arr)
console.log(arr2)
```

and this:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,6];
let arr2 = arr
arr.push('new item')
console.log(arr)
console.log(arr2)
```

Why in the first example, both array are different? (expect both equal with empty array), but in last example, when i `push`, both arrays chenged like expected?

Comment: In your first example 3rd line is creating a new array.  Your second example no new array is created.

Comment: When you assign your arrays in your second example you’re passing them by reference. The array is not cloned or duplicates, but is simply referenced by two variables.

Comment: its because in the first example you are giving asigning arr another array...which means it will get another adress in memory.

Comment: @Harish explained it really well. Sometimes when I am not sure I take a pen and draw a schema on the paper - like this one: https://i.ibb.co/x2zSwt0/jsschema.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript `Array` data type is a `reference-data-type`.

When you create an Array - `let arr = [1,2,3,4];`, an object `[1,2,3,4]` is created and its reference is saved as the value of the `arr` variable.

So, when you assign `arr2 = arr`, the reference value stored in `arr` is assigned to `arr2`. That's why when you try to update `arr2`, the `arr` variable is also getting updated because both variables `reference` the same object.

In the first example, since you have written `arr = []`, you are basically assigning a new array to the `arr` variable and it is referencing the new `[]` object. That's why you are seeing the difference.

**Edit:**
A detailed explanation.

Example 1:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4]; // arr is actually storing the [1,2,3,4]'s memory reference.
let arr2 = arr; // Now arr2 is also storing the [1,2,3,4]'s memory reference.
arr = []; // arr now stores a new [] object's memory reference.
console.log(arr); // logs - [] because arr is storing []'s memory reference.
console.log(arr2); // logs - [1,2,3,4] because arr2 is storing [1,2,3,4]'s memory reference.
```

Example 2:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,6]; // arr is actually storing the [1,2,3,6]'s memory reference.
let arr2 = arr; // Now arr2 is also storing the [1,2,3,6]'s memory reference.
arr.push('new item'); // [1,2,3,6] object is changed to [1,2,3,6, 'new item']. arr still references the same memory.
console.log(arr); // logs - [1,2,3,6, 'new item'] because arr is storing [1,2,3,6, 'new item']'s memory reference.
console.log(arr2); // logs - [1,2,3,6, 'new item'] because arr2 is also storing [1,2,3,6, 'new item']'s memory reference.
```

A [good article](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) to help you understand the concept better.

Answer (score 1):

Think of variables referring to arrays as arrows that point to something (that's what's really meant when people talk about reference types).

A statement such as:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,6];
```

can be read as: create an array with four elements (`[1,2,3,6]`) and let the variable called "`arr`" point to it.

```
let arr2 = arr
```

Then means, create a variable called "`arr2`" and let it point to the same array of four elements we already have.

The difference between your two examples now becomes easier to understand:

```
arr = []
```

Reads as: create an empty array, and make "`arr`" point to it. This doesn't say anything about "`arr2`" so that one continues to point to what it was pointing.

```
arr.push('new item')
```

This doesn't change any of the arrows, rather it modifies the array both "`arr`" and "`arr2`" are pointing at.